# How to save color of multiple element in localstorage in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<ul>
<li>item 1</li>
<li>item 2</li>
<li>item 3</li>
<li>item 4</li>
</ul>

<script>
document.querySelectorAll('li').forEach(e=>e.target.style.color='red');

</script>
```

Comment: What did you try with localStorage? Add whatever you attempted.

Comment: Put the colors in an array. Convert the array to JSON. Save the JSON in localStorage.

Comment: I want to store different list item color in localstorage and display again.

Comment: Does it save color when i refresh page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a JSON like this -

```
let color = {'item 1':'red','item 2':'yellow','item 3':'green','item 4':'black'}
sessionStorage.setItem("textColor", JSON.stringify(color));
```

and when you need it then

```
let storeColor = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("textColor"));
document.querySelectorAll('li').forEach(function (e, i) {
    e.style.color = storeColor[e.textContent];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get all diferent colors you want and for each one save with this
'''
let elemento_li = document.querySelectorAll('li');
elemento_li.forEach((elemento)=>{
Here you have to get the id or name of the element to use it like "key"
localStorage.setItem("key", elemento.style.color);
})'''